# Remote Access and Routing push DNS setting

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running a Windows Server 2012 r2 server with Remote Access and Routing enabled, and working as it should.

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to push DNS settings to the client.

I want to push server.host to 12.2.2.2 like you can do in /etc/hosts;

```
12.2.2.2   server.host
```

Is that even possible, or should all the clients push the DNS entry itself in the /etc/hosts or C:\Windows\System32\ drivers\etc\hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options to "push" the hosts file

- Use Group Policies when the clients are members of an Active Directory Domain
- Access through administrative share `\\YourClient\admin$\System32\drivers\etc`

Alternatives

- use an own domain entry when the public ip adress is static
- use something like [DynDNS](https://dyn.com/dns/) when the public adress isn't static

For security reasons you may consider to use an encrypted VPN like OpenVPN